# How can I create button with solid border(3d) in C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Panel `BorderStyle` can be set as `Fixed3D`, but buttons `BorderStyle` cannot be set as `Fixed3D`.

I also already tried `FlatAppearance` which is actualy flat style.
I also tried to override `button.paint` method to draw the shape but it didn't work here is the code

```
//Code for overiding paint method
private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, button1.ClientRectangle,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset);
}
```

If some one can give a idea it will be good , Thanks.

Comment: Follow the steps in the linked post.

Comment: I have tried that code but doesnot worked for me

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not a helpful description. What steps did you follow exactly and what was the result?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I tried your code, thank you, its amazing! Never noticed that before, that this is so easy to accomplish. Nevertheless I would suggest to change the Top and Left Color to ControlLight instead of ControlLightLight, and also ((Button)sender).ClientRectangle instead of direct referencing the name of the control.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Thanks for the feedback, in general I prefer to make it as a derived control and override `OnPaint` :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei you code works perfect, But in this case we have a white background, If we change the background color the effect will no longer active. Please suggest a work around for this case, Thanks

Comment: @MHanif `ControlPaintClass` have `Light`, `LightLight`, `Dark` and `DarkDark` methods which allow you to lighten or darken colors. You can also rely on any color that you think is suitable.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for the support,I got exactly what i was looking for :)